# Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou querendo buscar o total de linhas de uma consulta porém fica dando esse erro, já tentei usar a função row(), rowCount() e até mesmo verificar se encontrou algum resultado pra retornar e mesmo assim não cheguei na solução

> Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\topsamp-ci\application\models\Servidor_model.php on line
>   86

```
public function getVotosHoje($idServer){
    $data = date('Y-m-d');
    $select = array('id', 'data');
    $where = "idServidor = '$idServer' AND data = '$data'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->select($select);
    $retorno = $this->db->get('votos')->result();
    if($retorno->num_rows() > 0){
        return $retorno->num_rows();
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está errado `result()` não retorna um classe com funções, ele retorna os dados, portanto não possui a função `num_rows()`:

```
$retorno = $this->db->get('votos')->result();
if($retorno->num_rows() > 0){
    return $retorno->num_rows();
} else{
    return false;
}
```

O correto é usar assim:

```
$total = $this->db->get('votos')->num_rows();

if($total > 0){
    return $total;
} else{
    return false;
}
```

Agora se o que você quer é pegar os registros se for maior que 0 então faça assim:

```
$retorno = $this->db->get('votos');

if($retorno->num_rows() > 0){ //Conta registros
    return $retorno->result(); //Retorna os registros
} else{
    return false; //Retorna false se tiver 0 registros
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: @ViniciusAquino por favor marque a resposta como aceita.

Comment: Puts cara, funcionou porém só me retorna o ultimo registro da tabela, to chamando esse método dentro do foreach passando o id de cada item: <?= $this->server->getVotosHoje($v->id); ?>

Comment: @ViniciusAquino acho que entendi tua necessidade, eu editei a resposta, da uma olhada novamente.

Comment: Não funcionou, ele só me retorna 2 registros

Comment: @ViniciusAquino o problema é na tua query provavelmente porque você limitou por data `$data = date('Y-m-d');`, só vai aparecer os registros de hoje. Qualquer coisa tente assim `$retorno = $this->db->get();

if($retorno->num_rows() > 0){
    return $retorno->result();
}`

Comment: Me desculpe, estava vendo os dados no painel com a conta errada, está funcionando normalmente, obrigado pela ajuda!